# NullPointer while using dynamic view in android

Tags: java, android

I have created a dynamic view which repeats for a specific times. The view has 2 textViews and 2 radio buttons with default values. I want to change the Text values from program but getting nullpointer exception, Here is my code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout scrollViewLinearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent); // The layout inside scroll view
    //int count=50;
    for(int i = 0; i < Studentlist.length; i++){
        String data = Studentlist[i];
        String RollNum = data.split("--")[0];
        String Name = data.split("--")[1];

        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false);

        layout2.addView(item);
        layout2.setId(i);
        TextView trollnum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RollNum);
        trollnum.setText(RollNum);
        TextView tname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        tname.setText(Name);
        scrollViewLinearlayout.addView(layout2);


        Log.d("Id is: ", trollnum.getText().toString());
```

I am getting nullpointer at 'trollnum.setText(RollNum);'

How do i change the text in the View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find the view in the activity's layout where it doesn't exist instead of finding it in the layout you just inflated.

Replace

```
TextView trollnum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RollNum);
TextView tname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Name);
```

With

```
TextView trollnum = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.RollNum);
TextView tname = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.Name);
```